# DB connection in oracle

Tags: jdbc

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor  
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:localhost:1521:orcl

at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:261)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)  
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)  
at oraenter code herecle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)  
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)  
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)  
at com.test.Date.main(Date.java:13)
```

This is my code

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","system","tiger");
```

I veried `tnsnames.ora` file also

```
ORCL =
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SID = orcl)
    )
)
```

I added `ojdbc14.jar` in my classpath and i am using `oracle10g`

Could you please help me on this.

Comment: Can do you a tnsping from command prompt `tnsping orcl` and see what you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned check whether you are able to do a `tnsping` like `tnsping orcl` and if that works fine try to connect to your database from sqlplus or any tool like `TOAD` or `SQLDeveloper`. Post the errors if you are getting any, else use the following to connect to your database and see how it works.

```
    try {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
            Connection con = null;
            try {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","system","tiger");
                   } catch (SQLException ex) {            
            ex.printStackTrace();            
        } finally {
            close(connection);
        }
return
```

**`Update 1`**

Can you try with the following code

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521:orcl","system","tiger
```

If that doesn't work try this as well

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=<host>)(PORT=<port>))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=<service>)))
```

More information [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC)

Regards