# jdbc connection to oracle 10 XE

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle10g

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Oracle localhost connection error (ORA-12505)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805705/java-oracle-localhost-connection-error-ora-12505)

When I try to connect to Oracle 10g Express Edition, it gives me error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
localhost:1521:xe
```

My sample code:

```
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    Connection connection = null;
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "mk119", "mk119");
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
```

In database:

```
SQL> connect mk119
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1* select sys_context('userenv', 'instance_name') from dual
SQL> /

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','INSTANCE_NAME')
----------------------------------------------------------------------

xe

SQL>
```

Please help me on this.

**EDIT: Stacktrace:**

```
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
localhost:1521:xe

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:261)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
        at fingerprint.DatabaseTest.main(DatabaseTest.java:14)
```

**EDIT: Complete Code:**

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DatabaseTest {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            Connection connection = null;
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "mk119", "mk119");
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Connection created");
            stmt.close();
            connection.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805705/java-oracle-localhost-connection-error-ora-12505; make sure the connection url is ok (port, sid etc)

Comment: can you run, from a dos prompt, `tnsping xe`. if so , whats the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805705/java-oracle-localhost-connection-error-ora-12505), check the following (answer is the one from the related, maybe duplicate, question):

"Check if listener.ora file under the \admin\NETWORK directory has the following value:

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
```

"

Therefore check your connection url: host, port, sid, to make sure it is properly set.

Comment: Yes I checked. listener.ora was not having that information. I added that and restarted database, but still it is not working.

Comment: Are you getting any new errors?

Comment: no, same error I am getting

Comment: Try to check the tnsnames.ora file (probably located under $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin) and check the similar structure (add info if required).

Comment: Its there in tnsnames.ora, but still getting same erro

Comment: Could you please edit your description/question and paste some more of the stacktrace, if possible all of it?

Comment: edited question for complete code and stack trace

Comment: Can you try something like Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl", "scott", "tiger"); and then jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=<host>)(PORT=<port>))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=<service>))) (see http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC) - idea from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911459/db-connection-in-oracle)

Comment: Same error: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xe)))

Comment: Not the same error; the error code is different ORA-12514. Can you connect successfuly through sql developer or some other similar tool?

Comment: It got worked after restarting whole system. I don't know what problem may be. May be listener got messed. Thanks for you help.